# Install Packages in Custom Feed Using a .txt File

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I want to be able to install packages that exist in an Azure Artifacts feed.

I know this can be done using a command similar to this,

```
pip install <package-name> --extra-index-url https://<feed-name>:<DEVOPS_TOKEN>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/<project-name>/_packaging/<feed-name>/pypi/simple/
```

However, is there some way that I can maintain these packages and their versions in something like  a `requirements.txt` file and then install all of them using a single command like `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this to work is by including the `--extra-index-url` argument at the top of my `requirements.txt` file.

If I am to borrow from the answer @sachin has posted, it needed to be like this,

```
--extra-index-url https://:@pkgs.dev.azure.com///_packaging//pypi/simple/
stack==2.3.1
overflow==0.12.2
fun==0.63.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add them in the same **requirements.txt** file with the space.
like this :

stack==2.3.1
overflow==0.12.2
fun==0.63.0 --extra-index-url https://:@pkgs.dev.azure.com///_packaging//pypi/simple/

I pass any kind of extra arguments with this type, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Do you just use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the packages thereafter? This is not working for me.